# How to load only items that are visible in scrollview

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a long list of items I need to load in scrollview.

Currently I'm iterating over the list and adding it. But since the list is long the scrollview is extremely slow when loading and scrolling.

Is there a way to only have the items from the list that are suppose to be on screen loaded instead of loading all items?

Or is there another technique that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Use this.
https://github.com/Mukarillo/UnityDynamicScrollRect

Its a custom scroll view someone wrote that only loads the visible elements. You just have to write a custom function for instantiating the elements